# Run per-user specific launchd process as root

Tags: macos, mac, launchd

I need to figure out how to make a plist file for a certain user run as root. Since the user isn't root, the UserName string is ignored. I only want it to run for this one user, and no other users, so how would I go about doing that? The plist opens a program, and then runs some commands. The program is in usr/sbin and it runs as root, but the commands do not.

Comment: Ahhhh....I assume this is a Linux system but what is the distribution, and specific version identification.  This will help us help you.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm actually running this on Mac OSX 10.7.5